# How to read from lineX to lineY C#

Tags: c#, substring, text-parsing

Im trying to parse a .log file and have gotten to a part of it that looks like this:

```
2014-03-31 13:20:42,046 DEBUG 4B414D00000001184917.GetConventionalDataTask - GetCompressedLogResponse received: GetCompressedLogResponse: Id = GetCompressedLog, LoggerType = LoadProfileLogger, NumberOfRegisters = 5, NewLogId = 3281, Info = HeadOfLoggerIncluded

 LogID          RealTimeClock Logger_Status Logger_Data_Quality EnergyA14 EnergyA23 
          [KamDateTimeStatus]      [NoUnit]            [NoUnit]     [kWh]     [kWh] 
------ ---------------------- ------------- ------------------- --------- --------- 
  3264 02 2014-03-31T08:00:00          0000            00000000      0.17      0.00 
  3265 02 2014-03-31T08:15:00          0000            00000000      0.17      0.00 
  3266 02 2014-03-31T08:30:00          0000            00000000      0.17      0.00 
  3267 02 2014-03-31T08:45:00          0000            00000000      0.17      0.00  

2014-03-31 13:20:42,049 DEBUG 4B414D00000001184917.GetConventionalDataTask - Updated timestamp for logger LoadProfileLogger with time 31-03-2014 12:20:42
```

How do I get the lines between the 2 GetConventionalDataTask lines, so the program knows to start reading the lines from the line containing (GetCompressedLogResponse received:) to the line containing (Updated timestamp for logger)?

This is how far I have been able to get:

```
public static bool IsLoggerStart(string text)
    {
        return text.Contains("GetCompressedLogResponse received:");
    }
    public static bool IsLoggerEnd(string text)
    {
        return text.Contains("Updated timestamp for logger");
    }
    public static string GetLoggerType(string text)
    {
        return GetSubStrings(text, "LoggerType = ", ", ").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static string GetNumberOfRegisters(string text)
    {
        return GetSubStrings(text, "NumberOfRegisters = ", ", ").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static string GetNewLogId(string text)
    {
        return GetSubStrings(text, "NewLogId = ", ", ").FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And the objects I have created:

```
class CompressedLogResponse
{
    public LoggerAnnounce LoggerAnnounce { get; set; }
    public List<int> LogID { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> RealTimeClock { get; set; }
    public List<int> LoggerStatus { get; set; }
    public List<int> LoggerDataQuality { get; set; }
    public List<double> EnergyA14 { get; set; }
    public List<double> EnergyA23 { get; set; }
}
class LoggerAnnounce
{
    public string LoggerType { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRegisters { get; set; }
    public int NewLogId { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text between 2 GetConventionalDataTask using Regular expression

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("C:/log.txt");
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"GetConventionalDataTask\s-\s(.*).GetConventionalDataTask", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed you wanted GetConventionalDataTask to be included at the end, then regex pattern must be `Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"GetConventionalDataTask\s-\s(.*)\s-\sUpdated timestamp for logger", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549075(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548775(v=vs.100).aspx) methods for this:

```
var between = File.ReadLines("LogFile.log")
    .SkipWhile(s => !s.Contains("GetConventionalDataTask"))
    .TakeWhile(s => !s.Contains("Updated timestamp for logger"))
    .ToList();
```

The above will produce a list of strings representing lines from the log between the two markers.

Comment: I learned something new today with the SkipWhile and the TakeWhile, but this will get the first line entirely, and skip the last line entirely, which is not what the OP wants